Sending post though Powershell curl
For some reason when request is sent through Swagger it goes through without any issues

But when I try to do the same thing with powershell I get 400
curl -Method Post -Uri "http://localhost:32774/WeatherForecast" -Headers @{ accept = '*/*';"Content-Type" ="application/json" } -Body "test"


What can I do to fix it?

Curl has no body while PS your body is "test".  The content type is json and "test" is not json.

I saw */* in the text and *//* in the picture.

@jdweng I tried any combination of those. In Swagger it doesn't matter what content type is selected as well as body - endpoint receives them all. Why did you say that curl has no body? I clearly have -Body "test" at the end.

@shingo I was just testing things. I thought that maybe I need to escape it or something.

Even if you need to escape it, usually the escape char is \, right?

@user2463506 You might have -Body "test" in the PowerShell source code, but the "'s will be swallowed by the parser by the time the request reaches the web server. try -Body '"test"' or -Body ("test" |ConvertTo-Json -Compress) instead

Sending post though Powershell curl
This comment is the answer. What I was missing were quotes in body.
I wish I could mark the comment as answer.

It's better to directly include the solution in your post (with attribution).

Try
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://localhost:32774/WeatherForecast" -Method POST -Headers @{ accept = '*/*' } -ContentType 'application/json'


Sadly it's the same response. It's default ASP.NET Core endpoint.

what does your sever log say?

also, try just $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://localhost:32774/WeatherForecast" -Method POST -ContentType 'application/json'
